# Input Text in a dynamic javascript table

Tags: javascript, html

I try to generate a text field in a table:
The table gets bigger with the input of the user that's why I cant just write the
input syntax in the html document, because the cell isn´t generated from the beginning.

```
function tableAdd() {

   var table = document.getElementById("table");
   var titel = document.getElementById("Titel").value;
   var description = document.getElementById("Description").value; 




   var row = table.insertRow(); 


   var projectCell=row.insertCell(0);
   projectCell.innerHTML = titel;


   // down here is the problem

   var x =row.insertCell(1);
   x.innerHTML =  document.createElement("INPUT")
   x.innerHTML.setAttribute("type", "text");


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a reference of `HTMLInputElement` which is returned from the call to `document.createElement("input");` to the non-existent `innerHTML` property of a `HTMLTableRowElement` (`newRow` in my example) reference, returned by `insertCell(1);`.

Instead you can assign any text value to the `value` attribute of the `HTMLInputElement`(`input` variable in my example) and append the dynamic input to the newly created cell.

```js
function tableAdd() {
   var table = document.getElementById("table");
   var titel = document.getElementById("Titel").value;
   var description = document.getElementById("Description").value; 
   var row = table.insertRow(); 
   var projectCell=row.insertCell(0);
   projectCell.innerHTML = titel;
   var newRow =row.insertCell(1);
   var input = document.createElement("input");
   input.type = "text";
   input.value= description
   newRow.appendChild(input);
 }
 tableAdd();
```

```html
<body>
<input type="text" id="Titel" value="test"/>
<input type="text" id="Description" value="test"/>
<table id="table">
</table>
<button onclick="tableAdd()">add</button>
</body>
```

Here is the reference documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `x.innerHTML` is a string, not a html element. You need to set attribute on html element, not string. You can do like this:

```
var x =row.insertCell(1);
var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
y.setAttribute("type", "text");
x.appendChild(y);
```